# using backintime with a microSD drive or a RAVPower portable SSD

Tags: backintime

I have both a RAVPower portable SSD and a microSD. I am using a Dell XPS13 running Ubuntu 18. I'd like to save my snapshots to either of those two locations. But when I go into Settings/Where to Save Snapshot, I don't see either of those two choices. I can see them both, btw, through Nautilus, but not in the BIT menu. What to do?

Comment: Where are your drives mounted?  Hovering the mouse over the drive in Nautilus should display the mount point, or the lsblk command in Terminal will do so.  In Back In Time, you should be able to navigate from "Where to save snapshots" through the file system to the desired drive, e.g. Computer -> / -> media ->  8GBSDCARD.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be in /media/richb201/backintime which unfortunately is what I named the microSD. Thanks for your help. I got it working.